# update $rootScope.$broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

How can I update $rootScope.$broadcast with new value?

Consider this code:

```
var test = "fisk";

if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster')) {
    var monster_info = angular.element(this).find("img").attr("title");
    $http.get("lib/terrain.php", {params: { monster_data:monster_info}}).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('mapInfo', data);
    });
} else {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('mapInfo',test);
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.$on('mapInfo', function(event, mapInfo) {
    $scope.mapInfo = mapInfo;
    console.log($scope.mapInfo);
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="safeHtml(mapInfo)"></div>
```

This almost works. When I make the ajax-call, the mapInfo is updated and printed out at the page with the data. But when I'm not make the ajax-call, the value of fish is not printed out at the page. I can see that the $rootScope is being updated by the value fisk: console.log($scope.mapInfo), but it's not printed out.

Comment: There's a typo in your code. Your `else` block should be calling `$rootScope.$broadcast`. You've omitted the $ from `$broadcast`.

Comment: @mbcrute: Sorry, I missed it here, but I have it in my code. So it still don't work.

Comment: @mbcrute: Any other Idea?

Comment: What is triggering this code?

Comment: @Brocco: Which code? :)

Comment: @user500468 The code that triggers the broadcast. I was thinking it may be an issue that you may need to force a digest loop.

Comment: @Brocco: have a look at my new more informative question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522080/change-value-in-rootscope

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of your code

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5693/`
```

it can print out mapInfo