# Change value in $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have a table with a background like this: http://ast-ss.se/terrain/

You can navigate through the boxes by just clicking on them. I have also implemented the feature that random monsters, black dots, is generated at the map. You can navigate to the box and challenge the monster.

When I click on a box with a monster in it, I get the monster's specifications, lever, strength etc etc.

Here is the code snippet from my directive:

```
if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
{
    var monster_info = angular.element(this).find("img").attr("title");
    $http.get("lib/terrain.php", {params: { monster_data:monster_info}}).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('mapInfo', data);                     
    });
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `$rootScope.$broadcast` for this. Here is what I'm doing in my controller:

```
$scope.$on('mapInfo', function(event, mapInfo) {
    $scope.mapInfo = mapInfo;
    console.log($scope.mapInfo);
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="leftcontent_top">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Vildmarken</a></li>
        <li> | </li>
        <li><a href="#">Marknaden</a></li>
        <li> | </li>
        <li><a href="#">Värdshuset</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-bind-html="safeHtml(mapInfo)"></div>
<div ng-if="challengeMonster"><input type="submit" ng-click="doChallenge()" value="Utmana"></div>
```

This works fine. The information about the monster is printed out at the page. However, when you are in a box without a monster, I want to display information about the box you are in. Everytime you navigate to a new box, I want to print out information about that box. I have tried like this:

Directive:

```
angular.element('.click').click(function() {
    if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
    {
        var monster_info = angular.element(this).find("img").attr("title");
        $http.get("lib/terrain.php", {params: { monster_data:monster_info}}).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('mapInfo', data);                 
        });
    }
    else
    {
        test = angular.element(this).attr('id');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('mapInfo', test);
        angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
        angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');

        if(!angular.element(this).hasClass('dotted'))
        {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('mapInfo', test);
            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
            angular.element(this).html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have an else-statement with `$broadcast`, but the value of `test` is not printed out at the page. But if I click on a box with a monster in it, the information is printed out, but if I click in a empty box, nothing is printed out. As you can see in the controller, I run `console.log($scope.mapInfo)` and I can see that `$scope.mapInfo` contains the correct value.

Anyone?

Comment: Anyone who can help me?

Comment: I solved it with $timeout.